# ASCII-art git bash revision graph

Tags: git, graph, branch, git-bash, revision-graph

Anyone knows how to get in git bash ASCII - art graph like RevisionGraph from tortoiseGit?

(no listing of commits, just branch tree graph - which branch derives from which)

[TortoiseGit Revision Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXAXt.png)

I quickly look at git commands but it's look like there is no dedicated method and it's only achieveable with some bash script or combination of different git commands?

Answer (score 0):

No there's no such command, TortoiseGit does a thing of its own to make it.

You can derive part of its information with other commands, but not all at once, as far as I can tell.

By the way, if you wanted to find out which branch derives from which keep in mind that even TortoiseGit doesn't make a perfect work with that, in some situation it's actually impossible to know.

Comment: Thanks for feedback :)

Actually I found out that Webstorm can display nice readable graphs of git history and I can partially replace git text graph with this webstorm one.

Answer (score 0):

I've also been looking for this, and for me, the `--simplify-by-decoration` option of `git log` works pretty well as a substitute.

I regulary use something like

```sh
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph --simplify-by-decoration
```

which I have stored as a git [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases), so I can use it like `git revisions`.